# importing external jar in Geany

Tags: java, jsoup

I have problem with importing jar file and running in [Geany IDE](http://www.geany.org/). This is what I do:
I have downloaded [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). Extracted it and placed org file in my project directory. Then imported it to my source code:

```
    import org.jsoup.*;// why this does not import all
/*
instead I need to import everything manually
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
*/

        public class Crawler {

            public static void main (String args[]) {
                String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
          + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
            }
        }
```

When I tried to compile it within Geany it gave me error:

```
Crawler.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Document
symbol  : class Document
symbol  : class Document
```

What I am doing wrong, how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download the `jar` file and place the `external jar` in some `\lib` directory and add it to your project's classpath. As a good practice, instead of wildcard imports `org.jsoup.*` use `org.jsoup.Document`

Comment: " instead of wildcard imports org.jsoup.* use org.jsoup.Document " I am mostly interested in this sentence. Why?

Comment: Potential of classnames conflict, Explicit stating the dependency, makes compilation faster.

Comment: Could explain where `\lib` should be created? And how to *add it to your project's classpath*?

Comment: You don't need to create \lib, simply add the jar to your classpath