# How can I add a .jar in Geany?

Tags: geany

I'm attempting to add an external library to the Geany IDE. But, I have no idea how to go about this.

I've been working on this for a few days and the .jar I'm trying to add is `acm.jar`. What am I missing?

Comment: What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448752/importing-external-jar-in-geany) post?

Comment: It's apparently possible to [configure Geany for maven](http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/maven).

Comment: I've seen that post, and I tried to follow it to no avail. And as for Maven, I have no idea what that is and have no interest in using that, if I want a better or more improved IDE i will just switch to Eclipse.

Comment: Actually this is not an issue of Geany but of your Java search path.